# debugging on bsd using gdb or similar tootls

Tags: debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, freebsd, bsd

I have started using freebsd lately and realized gdb does not support remote debugging on it. 
Whenever, I try to do remote debugging using gdbserver, I run into SIGSEGV crashes and error message says can’t find definition of “r_debug_state”. 
Has anyone ever experienced this and solved it? 
Statically compiled single threaded programs can be compiled using gdbserver. However, other than that it is mostly looking difficult to use.

Let me know if anyone knows any other tools to do remote application debugging on bsd or how to fix the issue.

(I am on x64 freebsd 9)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the gdb that comes with the system? If so, you might considering installing the gdb that's in ports, `devel/gdb`.

Comment: I am using gdb which comes with system. I will try one from ports. But why would it be different?

Comment: Because the one is base in much older. The ports version is much newer.